# How to use in imported function in template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently run into the issue that my imported function is not referenced during render. It's easier explained by this code:

```
<template>
<div v-for="(addOn, index) in JSON.parse(this.restaurants[0].categories[categoryId].addons)">
    <label>
        <span>{{ addOn.name }} (+ ${{ addZeroes(addOn.price) }})</span>
    </label>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import { addZeroes } from "../../../js/helpers";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                // populated via AJAX
                restaurants: [
                    {
                        categories: []
                    }
                ],
            }
        },

    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

and the error is:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "addZeroes" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

What's the proper way to call a helper function inside a Vue template?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

You could add it to your component:

```
import { addZeroes } from "../../../js/helpers";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            // populated via AJAX
            restaurants: [
                {
                    categories: []
                }
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addZeroes // shorthand for addZeroes: addZeroes
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, and that's how I had it first, but since it is a method used throughout multiple components, I figured extracting it would be a good idea.

Comment: Templates implicitly access methods and properties by calling this.property. You’ll have to copy the imported function to each component that needs it, or look up the docs on mixins. With a mixin you can make the function added to each component, but be careful of name collisions.

Comment: Hi what I mean is assign the imported utility function to a method with the same name in your components methods, or alternatively, you can look into [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) as akatakritos suggests.